# How to export MapServer and featureserver links from QGIS

Tags: qgis, mapserver

QGIS has an option to export wmf, wcs, wfs ad xyz links all in one go. I have a lot of MapServer and featureserver layers, how do I export those all in one go?

Comment: Do you mean UMN MapServer layers (as the tag implies) or are you talking about some service provided by ESRI software?